# Enforcing an application Whitelist using JVMTI

Tags: java, c, jvmti

I am looking into possible ways to restrict the execution of all java applications on my JVM except for those on a whitelist.

Would a JVMTI agent be capable of analyzing an application within the JVM when it first attempts to load at startup and then preventing its execution if it was not found on our list of applications?

Any other information on achieving this whitelist implementation is more than welcome.

Comment: How are you executing the "applications" - directly, or in an application server or some other environment?

Comment: all are expected to be executed directly :)